# Wercker builds failing "could not read from remote repository"

Tags: github, wercker

As of last week, all builds for Wercker are failing due to an error when Wercker attempts to clone in to the Github repository.

```
Cloning into 'xxxx'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I've renewed the authorization for the Github repo, but the error remains. 
I was able to succesfully create builds with the same setting that are now failing on Wednesday.

Is anybody else having similar issues? Any thoughts on who to resolve this?

Comment: Turns out that Wercker made a change that requires an update to the known_hosts section in wercker.yml.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that Wercker made a change in the 'add-to-known_hosts' section in wercker.yml.

old structure:

```
add-to-known_hosts:
    hostname: github.com
    fingerprint: ...
```

new structure:

```
add-to-known_hosts@2.0.1:
    hostname: github.com
    fingerprint: ...
    type: rsa
```